# How to limit Google Cloud Tasks to execute 200 API requests per minute?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

The third party API has a limit of 200 API requests per minute. We are using Google Cloud tasks as our core engine to execute the API calls.

Wondering how we can setup the max dispatches and max concurrent dispatches such that maximum it processes 200 API requests per minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the rate limits when creating the Tasks Queue:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. with Max dispatches set to 3, it will dispatch maximum 180 jobs per minute. However if we have only 100 jobs, how we can dynamically set that it can dispatch more than 3 jobs per second so 100 jobs are completed faster than 30 seconds

Comment: @DenishFaldu you can use the Google Cloud's [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues/patch) to update a queue but I doubt if it's a good idea to update that frequently.